# How implement Graph API beta in ASP.NET Core App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0, azure-ad-graph-api

The following code (.NET 6) works with Graph v1.0.

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using System;

namespace Birthway
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }



        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string[] initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            // uncomment the following 3 lines to get ClientSecret from KeyVault
            //string tenantId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:TenantId");
            //services.Configure<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>(
            //   options => { options.ClientSecret = GetSecretFromKeyVault(tenantId, "ENTER_YOUR_SECRET_NAME_HERE"); });

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            services.AddRazorPages()
                  .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            // Add the UI support to handle claims challenges
            services.AddServerSideBlazor()
               .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }

        /// Gets the secret from key vault via an enabled Managed Identity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/blob/master/README.md</remarks>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string GetSecretFromKeyVault(string tenantId, string secretName)
        {
            // this should point to your vault's URI, like https://<yourkeyvault>.vault.azure.net/
            string uri = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_URI");
            DefaultAzureCredentialOptions options = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions();

            // Specify the tenant ID to use the dev credentials when running the app locally
            options.VisualStudioTenantId = tenantId;
            options.SharedTokenCacheTenantId = tenantId;
            SecretClient client = new SecretClient(new Uri(uri), new DefaultAzureCredential(options));

            // The secret name, for example if the full url to the secret is https://<yourkeyvault>.vault.azure.net/secrets/ENTER_YOUR_SECRET_NAME_HERE
            Response<KeyVaultSecret> secret = client.GetSecretAsync(secretName).Result;

            return secret.Value.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Azure;
using Birthway.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Beta;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;

namespace Birthway.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
        private readonly MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler _consentHandler;
        private readonly string[] _graphScopes;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration, Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient,
                            MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler consentHandler)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
            _consentHandler = consentHandler;
            _graphScopes = configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
        }

        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            User currentUser = null;

            try
            {
                currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
            }
            // Catch CAE exception from Graph SDK
            catch (ServiceException svcex) when (svcex.Message.Contains("Continuous access evaluation resulted in claims challenge"))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{svcex}");
                    string claimChallenge = WwwAuthenticateParameters.GetClaimChallengeFromResponseHeaders(svcex.ResponseHeaders);
                    _consentHandler.ChallengeUser(_graphScopes, claimChallenge);
                    return new EmptyResult();
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    _consentHandler.HandleException(ex2);
                }
            }

            try
            {
                // Get user photo
                using (var photoStream = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.GetAsync())
                {
                    byte[] photoByte = ((MemoryStream)photoStream).ToArray();
                    ViewData["Photo"] = Convert.ToBase64String(photoByte);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception pex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{pex.Message}");
                ViewData["Photo"] = null;
            }

            ViewData["Me"] = currentUser;
            return View();
        }
   }
}
```

[image]

---

I need this to work with Graph beta, that's why I change the BaseUrl value to "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta" (appsettings.json), instantiate the GraphServiceClient object this time with Microsoft.Graph.Beta and adapt the code (HomeController.cs). It seems to fail in the container part but I don't understand why.

My changes:

```
using Birthway.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Beta;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;

namespace Birthway.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly Microsoft.Graph.Beta.GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
        private readonly MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler _consentHandler;
        private readonly string[] _graphScopes;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration, Microsoft.Graph.Beta.GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient,
                            MicrosoftIdentityConsentAndConditionalAccessHandler consentHandler)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
            _consentHandler = consentHandler;
            _graphScopes = configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
        }

        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models.User currentUser = null;

            try
            {
                currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
            }
            // Catch CAE exception from Graph SDK
            catch (ServiceException svcex) when (svcex.Message.Contains("Continuous access evaluation resulted in claims challenge"))
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{svcex}");
                    string claimChallenge = WwwAuthenticateParameters.GetClaimChallengeFromResponseHeaders(svcex.ResponseHeaders);
                    _consentHandler.ChallengeUser(_graphScopes, claimChallenge);
                    return new EmptyResult();
                }
                catch (Exception ex2)
                {
                    _consentHandler.HandleException(ex2);
                }
            }

            try
            {
                // Get user photo
                using (var photoStream = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.GetAsync())
                {
                    byte[] photoByte = ((MemoryStream)photoStream).ToArray();
                    ViewData["Photo"] = Convert.ToBase64String(photoByte);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception pex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{pex.Message}");
                ViewData["Photo"] = null;
            }

            ViewData["Me"] = currentUser;
            return View();
        }
   }
}
```

The error:

[image]

Comment: Did install beta version package solve the issue?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/tree/a8bf5aa2187edc7be79e97620ba67aa9687f45df/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient#you-can-now-use-both-microsoft-graph-and-microsoft-graph-beta If it helps or not

Comment: I have installed "Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" which I was missing but the HomeController constructor does not recognize GraphBetaServiceClient. Also I don't know where these two lines go: using GraphServiceClient = Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient;
using GraphBetaServiceClient = Microsoft.Graph.GraphBetaServiceClient;

Comment: Hi, pls continue to use `Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient` but not the `Microsoft.Graph.Beta.GraphServiceClient`, just change `Microsoft.Graph` to `Microsoft.Graph.Beta`.

Comment: I have followed the steps of "You can now use both Microsoft Graph and Microsoft Graph Beta", I have uninstalled Microsoft.Graph.Beta.GraphServiceClient and I have added Microsoft.Graph.Beta to the GraphServiceClient object that I use as an input parameter in the constructor... it does not work since it does not detect Beta in the Microsoft.Graph library.

Comment: I already proved using `Microsoft.Graph.Beta` + `Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient` could allow you to use `graphServiceClient` to call beta version API. Just like you see in the api response, we are able to see the odata link is `/beta`. I'll post my controller below

Comment: I copy all the nugests except the first two that generate an error (I don't think they are necessary for the request) but it generated this error: CS7069 Reference to type 'IAuthenticationProvider' confirms that it is defined in 'Microsoft.Graph.Core', but was not found

Comment: when we use package `Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph` we will get error `CS7069 Reference to type 'IAuthenticationProvider' confirms that it is defined in 'Microsoft.Graph.Core'`. Using `Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient` instead will solve the issue. I also met this error when I test in my side. `Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph` is for graph SDK v4.x, but now we are using v5.x

Comment: I don't really understand how to do it. It fails for me in Startup on this line ".AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))". If I remove it it won't fail me but it is important. My Startup:

    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

Comment: your code in the startup is correct, what I used in my Program.cs file is the same as yours because I just copied your code. But I also faced some compilance issue at first, I solved them by changing the nuget packages. Could you pls copy the content I shared in `<ItemGroup>` and paste to your project then rebuild your project?

Comment: Wow now it works!! But now it fails when I use _graphServiceClient.Me.Profile.GetAsync(); InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Graph.Beta.GraphServiceClient' while attempting to activate 'WebMvcBetaAad.Controllers.HomeController'.

Comment: yes I reproduced your issue in my side. In my controller, at first I have `//using Microsoft.Graph; using Microsoft.Graph.Beta;` which would make `GraphServiceClient` to be the beta version, but when I inject it into controller, in the constructure, I wrote `public HomeController(Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient` which forcing it to not use the beta version. Just like what I said above, we only need to install the `Microsoft.Graph.Beta` package and keep using `Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient` package, so when we try to use beta version GraphServiceClient, it crashed.

Comment: solution to solve your latest exception is, comment the `using Microsoft.Graph.Beta` and having `using Microsoft.Graph` instead. Or keep using `using Microsoft.Graph.Beta` but when we inject `GraphServiceClient`, we write `public HomeController(Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient`.

Comment: @codeNightmare can we say the issue is solved now?

Answer (score 0):

check the `Include prerelease` option, then searching for the beta version package

[image]

=========================================

I reproduced the issue in my side:

[image]

Then if we continue to use `Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient` instead of `Microsoft.Graph.Beta.GraphServiceClient` could solve the issue. Let's see the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/use-beta?tabs=csharp) for using Beta version SDK, it doesn't ask us to use beta version `GraphServiceClient`:

> In order to call the beta API, you must install the
> Microsoft.Graph.Beta package. Usage is the same as the Microsoft.Graph
> package.

[image]

Here's the nuget packages I use and I test.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.10" NoWarn="NU1605" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.10" NoWarn="NU1605" />
   <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.25.0" />-->
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Beta" Version="5.46.0-preview" />
   <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="3.0.11-preview.1" />-->
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.55.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.13.3" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient" Version="2.13.3" />
   <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClientBeta" Version="2.13.3" />-->
   <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraphBeta" Version="2.13.3" />-->
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="2.13.3" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

my controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using WebMvcBetaAad.Models;
//using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Beta;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace WebMvcBetaAad.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;


        public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
        {
            var currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

=========================================

My Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

string[] initialScopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help :) As standard I have NuGgets: "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design", "Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" and "Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClientBeta". I just downloaded what you recommended and the error persists.